# ¿Cómo accedo a una variable de un tipo genérico (T)? - Scala

Tags: scala

Como están? Tengo este trait, que es como un "repositorio" que guarda cosas de un tipo específico.

```
trait Repositorio[T]{
  //Se guarda el "t" en una lista. 
  def store(t: T): Unit
}
```

Ahora me pidieron que se guarden SOLAMENTE los objetos que tengan un ID

Entonces no se me ocurre como hacer para poder acceder a ese "id" cuando el tipo es un "T" no definido, estaba pensando algo así pero claramente no funciona nada

```
trait Repositorio[T]{ 
  def store(t: T): Unit = {
    require(!t.id.eq(null))
  }
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Antes de nada, `T` es una _variable de tipo genérico_, no confundir con `Any`, el tipo que comprende a todos los tipos. Cuando dices que SOLO debe guardar objetos que tenga ID, ¿qué se supone que debe pasar si intentas guardar un objeto que no tenga ese atributo? El comportamiento debería estar definido en tiempo de compilación, sin sacar errores en tiempo de ejecución. Si pones una restricción sobre cómo tiene que ser un tipo, esa restricción tiene que estar descrita al definir el tipo `T`.

Comment: Si, tenés razón con la del tipo genérico. Vamos a agregar ahora una restricción a nuestro repositorio: todos los elementos que allí se guarden deberán tener un atributo id de tipo entero.
El ejercicio dice esto:
Modificar el trait Repositorio[T] para que solamente acepte objetos que tengan un atributo id de tipo entero.
Según entiendo cuando haces repositorio.store(elem) el elemento que se pasa por param tienen que tener una variable id

Comment: De acuerdo. Como habías puesto `require`, se puede interpretar que querías lanzar una excepción, pero la realidad es que siempre se conoce en tiempo de compilación si un objeto tiene un atributo `id`, por lo que no tiene sentido esperar a la ejecución. Ahora te doy una respuesta completa.

Answer (score 0):

No sé exáctamente si te va a servir de respuesta.

Tal como dije en un comentario, en tiempo de compilación se sabe si un objeto tiene un atributo o no. No es como en los lenguajes dinámicos en los que es posible añadir o eliminar atributos durante la ejecución.

Por eso será el compilador quien haga el trabajo de impedir que el *trait* sea usado por un objeto inapropiado.

Lo primero es definir el tipo de objeto que queremos que use el *trait*:

```scala
trait ConID {
  val id: Int
}
```

E implementamos nuestro repositorio para que use este tipo:

```scala
class MyRepo[T <: ConID] extends Repositorio[T] {
  var _repo: Map[Int, T] = Map()
  def store(t: T) = { _repo = _repo + (t.id -> t) }
}
```

Nuestro repositorio `MyRepo` añade la restricción sobre la variable de tipo genérica indicando que debe ser subtipo de `ConID`.

Podemos probar el funcionamiento:

```scala
case class IdName(id: Int, name: String) extends ConID
case class IdValue(id: Int, value: Double) extends ConID

val repo = new MyRepo[ConID]()

repo.store(IdName(0, "Pepe"))
repo.store(IdValue(1, 2.0))

println(repo._repo)
// Map(0 -> IdName(0,Pepe), 1 -> IdValue(1,2.0))
```

Estamos algo limitados por estar imponiendo que los tipos del repositorio tienen que ser subtipos de `ConID`. Pero podemos hacerlo mejor usando *tipos estructurales*. Nos basta con que tenga un atributo `id: Int`:

```scala
class MyRepo[T <: { val id: Int}] extends Repositorio[T] {
  var _repo: Map[Int, T] = Map()
  def store(t: T) = { _repo = _repo + (t.id -> t) }
}
```

Usando *tipos estructurales*, nuestro respositorio podrá usar cualquier tipo, sin obligación de derivar de `ConID`:

```scala
case class IdName(id: Int, name: String)
case class IdValue(id: Int, value: Double)

val repo = new MyRepo[{val id: Int}]()

repo.store(IdName(0, "Pepe"))
repo.store(IdValue(1, 2.0))

println(repo._repo)
// Map(0 -> IdName(0,Pepe), 1 -> IdValue(1,2.0))

repo.store(42)
// Error de compilación: type mismatch

repo.store(new {val id = 42})
```

Normalmente, cuando se trabaja con tipos estructurales se suelen dejar sin nombre para que quede claro. Si fueran estructuras más complejas que la que estamos usando, se podría usar un alias:

```scala
type ConID = { val id: Int }  // tipo estructural

class MyRepo[T <: ConID] extends Repositorio[T] {
  var _repo: Map[Int, T] = Map()
  def store(t: T) = { _repo = _repo + (t.id -> t) }
} 

val repo = new MyRepo[ConID]()
```

Comment: Gracias !! Me sirvió la forma estructural. Te agradezco mucho! Estuve mucho tiempo probando cosas pero nada sirvió. Saludos!